# Какой механизм хранит значение инициализации?

Tags: javascript, объекты, инициализация

Помогите пожалуйста разобраться. Я создаю объект, инициализируя его значениями. Мне не совсем понятен механизм, при помощи которого позже я могу вывести в консоль одно из значений инициализации.

[JSFILLDE](http://jsfiddle.net/zlodiak/5bhtp4xm/2/)

```
function Product(id, description) {
    this.getId = function() {
        return id;
    };
    this.getDescription = function() {
        return description;
    };  
}

const prod = new Product(1, 'MacBook Air');

console.log('id', prod.getId());
```

Есть хорошая [статья](https://learn.javascript.ru/constructor-new), которая поясняет как создаётся объект в общем случае. Но в моём кода случай частный, то есть он немного отличается.

Ход моих рассуждений такой, поправьте, если я не прав:

1. при помощи new я создаю новый объект из конструктора Product. При
   этом инициализирую его двумя значениями.
2. this получает свойство на создающийся объект
3. создаётся новое свойство этого объекта getId
4. где-то в памяти создаётся функция, которая возвращает 1.
5. эта функция будет существовать пока существует хотя бы одна ссылка
   на неё(а свойство getId как раз ссылается на неё)
6. далее внешняя функция console.log() выводит результат обращения к
   getId, а значит опосредованно к function() { return 1; };
7. если мы удалим объект prod, то ссылка на функцию, которая возвращает
   1 перестанет существовать. а значит и сама функция, которая
   возвращает 1 со временем будет уничтожена сборщиком мусора

Comment: в вашем случае нужно почитать про замыкания, в вашем примере он учавствует

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> this получает свойство на создающийся объект

Ссылку на объект, а не св-во

> где-то в памяти создаётся функция, которая возвращает 1.

Не 1, а значение переменной ( при некоторых условиях его тоже можно поменять )

Ваш случай можно рассмотреть и без создания объекта, потому что он по большей части относится именно к замыканию.

Разберем пример проще

```
function foo(value) {
  return function foo1() {
    return value;
  }
}

const foo1 = foo('foo1')
console.log(foo1())
```

Когда вызывает функция, не важно просто вызов или через `new`, создается локальная область видимости. Туда попадают переменные функции и ее параметры, которые мы передали. В примере выше это будет переменная `value` ( одна из них ). Кроме локальной области видимости, функция так же имеет ссылку на вышестоящую область видимости.

Поэтому, когда мы возвращаем `foo1`, у нее будет ссылка на область видимости, которая является локальной областью видимости `foo` и так как `foo1` все еще существует, то и область видимости `foo` не уничтожается.

Это и есть замыкание, к созданию объектов, отношение не имеет.